# How to deliver images effectively using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, high-load

My asp.net application creates, stores in memory and shows images to user. Standard HttpHandler gets thread from pool to deliver each image. I think it's not effectively. Can asp.net deliver images more effectively than HttpHandler?

Upd: images are temporary. We store it during 1 hour.

Comment: What does effective mean?  I've used that technique with great success.  I would do away with the handler unless you see good reason to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS serving the images from disk it the most efficient not sure about effective, as well as using a CDN if possible.

Comment: I fogot important feature. Images are stored during one hour.

Answer (score 0):

For a heavy loaded/visited site, it make sense to put it as file system